# How to prove this function is actually constant?

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be function $\:f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which for any $x$, $f\left(x\right)=f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$. 
Also, $f$ continuous at $x=0$.
Show that $f$ is constant function.

So far i saw something here [Does $f(x) = f(2x)$ for all real $x$, imply that $f(x)$ is a constant function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374507/does-fx-f2x-for-all-real-x-imply-that-fx-is-a-constant-function), but i don't understand the solution that he was given. I thought about assuming that there exist $a,b$ such that $f\left(a\right)\ne f\left(b\right)$ and get a contradict.

Any ideas about what give me that $f$ is continuous at $0$? and any ideas about a way to prove that? tnx in advance!

Comment: @ADG first, i wrote in my question that i look at this. second, look for "Also" that i wrote and find the difference between the questions.

Comment: the only difference is that you can't understand that solution, better comment under the answer your confusion?

Comment: @ADG there, f is continuous in every point. here just in 0.

Comment: that doesn't make a difference, we are only concerned about x=0.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the exact same as the one you linked to. I will provide one extra step to aid in convincing you of this. 
$f(x)=f(\frac{x}{2})=f(\frac{x}{4})=f(\frac{x}{8})=...=f(\frac{x}{2^n})$.
Can you use this fact to reconcile the answers provided in your linked solution?

Comment: tnx @Sloan. i figured this steps you wrote. i just don't understand the conclusion , "so f(x)=limn→∞f(x/2n)=f(0) by continuity.". why it derives from continuity? and it derives from continuity in **every** point or just in $0$?

Comment: As the others have pointed out, $x=0$ is the sole point of interest; $f$ should be constantly $f(0)$ as $f(x)=f(\frac{x}{2^n})$ for arbitrarily large values of $n$ and for any $x$.