# The limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(2^{-n}x)$ for different $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $f:\Bbb R\backslash \{0\} \to\Bbb R$ is continuous and that for each $x\in\Bbb R\backslash \{0\}$ the limit 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(2^{-n}x)$$
exists. Is it true that the limit must have the same value for all such $x$?

It's not hard to construct a counterexample if we only require $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(2^{-n}x_i)=L_i$ for only finite choices of $x_i$, $i=1,\dots,k$. However, I don't see how one can construct a counterexample in the case I'm interested in.

---

**Edit:** I'm not feeling well today so I overlooked such a simple amswer. Just let $f$ be a linear interpolation that looks like a triangle on [1/2,1] and extend by $f(2x)=f(x)$. This is a counterexample.

Comment: My answer here is relevant to constructing a large class of counter examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215378/if-fx-f2x-then-how-do-we-get-the-solution-fx-sin-log-a-x-thro/3215415#3215415

Answer (score 2):

How about $f(x)=\sin(2\pi\log_{2}x)$?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Take $f(x)=\text{sign}(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$. Obviously the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(2^{-n}x)=\text{sign}(x)$$

is $1$ if $x>0$ and $-1$ if $x<0$, which is a counterexample.

An example that seems more like what you're asking is to take $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\ln(2)}\ln(x)\right)$. Note that this means that $f(x)=f(2x)$ for all positive real $x$, which means that the limit is $1$ for some positive real $x$ and $-1$ for others (or anywhere in between). Graphically, this function oscillates rapidly as $x\to0$, perfectly syncing up halving $x$ to land on the next peak/trough.

Comment: I also immediately constructed a counterexample after I posted the question haha and it looks very similar to yours. Thank you nonetheless.