# Are continous function with condition f(x)=f(2x) constant when 0 is not in domain?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in(0,\infty)$,
$$f(2x)=f(x)$$

Now I wanna know if we can conclude from the given information that $f$ is constant, If yes, then how? if no, then can you give a counter example.

---

This is where I can reach

$$f(x_0)=f\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{x_0}{2^2}\right)=\cdots=\lim_{n\to \infty} f\left(\frac{x_0}{2^n}\right)$$

Now here what can we say about $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f\left(\frac{x_0}{2^n}\right)$$

we cant say its equal to $f(0)$ as $0$ is not in domain, does this limit even exist?, if we can just somehow show that this limit exists then I guess we will be done but I dont know how to show this and this is where I am stuck.

Comment: With the substution $x =\ln(u)$ this is equivalent to the question whether a (continuous) periodic function is constant.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215378/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3256399/42969.

Comment: Take an arbitrary continuous $g:[1,2]\to\mathbb R$ with $g(1)=g(2)$ and set
$$\forall j: x\in[2^j,2^{j-1})\implies f(x):= g(2^{-j}x)$$