# Prove $\int_{na}^{nb}f(x)dx=n\int_a^bf(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that
>   $$
> \int_{na}^{nb}f(x)dx=n\int_a^bf(x)dx
> $$

This is given as a general property of definite integrals in my reference. Is it true for all cases ?

If it is true I have no clue of how to prove it ?

$$
t=nx\implies dt=n.dx\\
\int_{na}^{nb}f(x)dx=\int_{na}^{nb}f\big(\frac{t}{n}\big).\frac{dt}{n}
$$

Comment: This is super obviously false. Let $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $n =2$ as a quick example. The claim is that $\int_0^2 f(x) dx = 2 \int_0^1 f(x) dx$. Most functions will fail this; feel free to choose one

Comment: It's actually $\int_{na}^{nb} f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \ dx = n \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx$ and this follows from an easy substitution.

Comment: I think it's a typing error or something like that. On the right side, instead of $f(x)$, there were $f(nx)$. That's my blind guess because there is no way you can make this equality true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true as Brevan points out in comments. But there are two changes I can think of you can make to get a true statement. The first is a change of variables, but you typed it wrong. It should be $t=x/n$ to remove the $n$ multiplying $a,b$: then $dt = dx/n$ and $x=nt$, so
$$ \int_{na}^{nb} f(x) dx = n \int_a^b f(nt) dt$$
or equivalently from MathematicsStudent1122's comment
$$  \int_{na}^{nb} f(x/n) dx =  \int_a^b f(t) dt$$
The second is if $n$ is a special number for $f$ such that $f(t) = f(nt)$. Nontrivial (i.e. nonconstant) such functions exist; see Alex's counterexample [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374507/80734): $$f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\log x}{\frac{\log2}{2\pi}}\right)$$
I've made a moving [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wrc4h9nl7e), showing $f(x)$ and $f(kx)$ as $k$ varies between $1$ and $2$...here's what this $f$ looks like:
[image]

Comment: how did my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489313/the-chromatic-number-of-the-product-of-two-4-chromatic-graphs-is-4/3496964#3496964) not answer the question? OP asked where they can find paper and I provided link.

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't know if you can see the list of people who voted to close; they are Calvin Khor(me), Shailesh, José Carlos Santos, Andrews, Matthew Daly, The Demonix _ Hermit. I would have undid my vote after you messaged, if I knew how...but I don't think that it mattered, I suspect the other votes that all came later were because they saw only a link in your answer, or maybe they didn't even notice that there was a link, since you hyperlinked it to a single `.` which is hard to notice

Comment: @mathworker21 A padding sentence like "it can be found in the Journal of ABC Volume XXIV, linked [here]" would make it obvious that your answer is not spam / of only one character. The bounty ends in 23 hours, if you make the answer read like "an answer" and post in somewhere appropriate in meta / ping a mod I would expect things to be OK

Comment: @mathworker21 although its not clear to me that OP was happy with the link to springer, since he wanted the paper emailed to him. And if you want the bounty automatically you'll need a positive score on your answer I think

Comment: Even if they only saw a link to my answer, I have absolutely no idea why they'd vote to delete.

Comment: Oh wow, I just undeleted it lol. Didn't need moderators or anyone. And by the way, I messaged everyone who deleted it asking why, and none of them responded.

Comment: It looks like spam on first sight, imo. but thats hillarious lol glad its undeleted @mathworker21

Answer (score 2):

$
\int_{na}^{nb}f(x)dx=n\int_a^bf(x)dx
$
is false, just set $a=0$ and then only for specific cases of $f,b$ it can be true, but in general it will be false.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is continuos, and $b>a>0$.

MVT for integration:

1)$I_1:=\displaystyle{ \int_{na}^{nb}}f(x)dx=f(s)n(b-a)$, $s \in [na,nb]$.

2) $I_2:= n\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)dx=nf(t)(b-a)$, $t \in [a,b]$.

Let $n$, positive integer, be large enough s.t. $[a,b]\cap[na,nb]=\emptyset$, i.e. the two intervals do not overlap.

For any strictly  increasing $f$:

$f(s) >f(t)$, hence

$I_1>I_2$.